# Get a substring from string multiple times

Tags: java, regex, javafx

I have a String that I don't know how long it is or what caracters are used in it.
I want to search in the string and get any substring found inside "" .
I tried to use pattern.compile but it always return an empty string

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\".\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(mystring);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group().toString());
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.+?` to get all characters inside `""` with grouping

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\".+?\"");
```

The `.+` specifies that you want at least one or more characters inside the quotations. The `?` specifies that it is a reluctant quantifier, which means it will put different quotations into different groups.

Unit test example:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String test = "speak \"friend\" and \"enter\"";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\".+?\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group().toString().replace("\"", ""));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
friend
enter
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
One question, in your example, how can i show friend and enter without the "" .

Comment: @Ayhem the easiest way is to just scrub the quotations, like `.replace("\"", "")`

Answer (score 0):

That is because your regex actually searches for one character between " and " ... if you want to search for more character, you should rewrite your regex to `"\".?\""`